# Redirect https://www to https://

Tags: ssl, nginx, https

I try to redirect https://www.subdomain.website.com to https://subdomain.website.com - but  I have "Your connection is not private" like petenetlive.com/KB/Media/0000992/00001.png

It's ok without www because it's managed by Cloudflare.
Do you know why ?

```
server {
       listen 443;
       server_name www.irc.mywebsite.lol;
       return 301 https://irc.mywebsite.lol;

      ssl on;
      ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
}

server {
        server_name     www.irc.mywebsite.lol;
        rewrite ^(.*)   https://irc.mywebsite.lol$1 permanent;
}


server {
        # Port
        listen 80;

        # Hostname
        server_name irc.mywebsite.lol;

        # Logs (acces et erreurs)
        access_log /var/log/nginx/irc.mywebsite.lol.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/irc.mywebsite.lol.error.log;
         location / {
                        proxy_set_header Host $host;
                        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                        proxy_set_header x-forwarded-for
                        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                        proxy_pass http://localhost:7778/;
                        proxy_redirect default;
                        # Websocket support (from version 1.4)
                        proxy_http_version 1.1;
                        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the certificate you use does not cover www.subdomain.example.com. This means the https connection to this sites results in a SSL warning (hostname does not match certificate). And since the redirect is only done *after* the successful SSL handshake no redirect will happen.

To fix this you need a certificate which covers www.subdomain.example.com. Note that wildcard certificates for *.example.com will not be enough since a wildcard covers only the single leftmost label of the hostname.

Comment: Hello, do you mean Common Name: www.irc.mywebsite.lol when I create the certificate ?

Comment: @BaraqueObahamas: either have your own certificate for this name but you also may include it as an additional name (subject alternative names) in  another certificate.